# Families of sets with the FIP or finite set of transversals

Tags: combinatorics

I've come with this question that I cannot answer. I've tried unsuccessfully to construct a counterexample.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of sets such that any two sets in the family  have nonempty intersection. One of the following must hold

(1) $\mathcal{F}$ has the finite intersection property.

(2) $\mathcal{F}$ has a finte set of transversals, i.e. there is a finite sex $X\subseteq \cup\mathcal{F}$ such that, for every $F\in\mathcal{F}$, $F\cap X\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: What if $F_n$ is the numbers exceeding $n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson you mean $F_n=\{m : m>n \}$? Those would have the finite intersection property.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misremembered what the FIP was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_n=\{n,n+1,n+2,\dots\}$ for $n=4,5,6,\dots$, let $F_1=\{1,2,4,7,10,13,\dots\}$, $F_2=\{1,3,5,8,11,14,\dots\}$, $F_3=\{2,3,6,9,12,15,\dots\}$. Then $F_i\cap F_j\ne\emptyset$, $F_1\cap F_2\cap F_3=\emptyset$, and any transversal must have arbitrarily large elements, hence, must be infinite.

Here's a wilder example. For $i=0,1,2,\dots$, let $L_i$ be the line given by the equation $y=i(x-i)$. Then $L_m$ and $L_n$ intersect at $(m+n,mn)$; if $m,n,r$ are distinct, then there is no point on all three of $L_m,L_n,L_r$; and since no point is on more than two lines, there is no finite transversal.

Comment: Great thank you